# What are the pros and cons of different research career paths?

Tags: career-path, academic-life, industry

As a student thinking about a career in research, more precisely pure or fundamental research, I would like to know more about possible careers. I haven't decided on the field yet, so I'm interested in as many fields as possible.

First of all, academia seems to be the most obvious path. But I don't really like the idea that you have to have other responsibilities besides research. So the question is how much time do other responsibilities take, such as writing grants, teaching, etc., and are there no academic positions where you focus entirely on research?

The next option would be industry. But the question here is: is it possible to do basic research in the industry? and if so, wouldn't this be a better option, given that it relieves you of other responsibilities and you can focus on research? (I know it depends a lot on the field)

Other paths I would also like to hear about: maybe both academia and industry would be an option or research institutes and institutes for advanced studies or starting your own research company. Any other suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "... other responsibilities besides research" -- please be reminded that universities exist to teach.  In most universities, teaching pays your salary.  Research is something you do on the 'side'.  If you do not have students, you do not have a job, meaning no research!

Comment: And national labs fit where?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you seem too unfocused to have any real answer make sense to you. The main benefit of a life of research is the internal satisfaction you get from discovering the unknown. But the techniques that you need to use to get there differ so radically that a general answer is probably impossible. What a mathematician does to discover truth and what, say, Kurt Vonnegut did are totally unlike one another.

Pure research in terms of just pushing back the shadows of the unknown is pretty rare and has always been. Charles Darwin was able to manage it without really being employed at all. It wasn't obvious what Albert Einstein was actually qualified for, so he spent a number of years in the Patent Office and did much of his deep thinking there, IIRC.

University research is seldom "just" research until the late stages of your career, say, after 50 years old, when you can be funded by grants and you have a track record that keeps the grants flowing. Industrial research, these days, almost always has a product focus. You need to contribute to the bottom line. The exceptions exist, but they are rare, and you need to get very well established before you become the exception.

The rewards don't involve money, and the money can be fairly meager compared to, say, law or economics. And the cons can involve never really being "done" - always thinking about the problem(s) at hand.

I'd suggest that you wait for a while and study quite a lot of things until you find something that grabs you and won't let go. Then you can ask a question like this and get a meaningful answer for yourself. There is a saying that "You don't choose mathematics (for a career). Mathematics chooses you." It is pretty similar in other fields. You will really only be successful in research if you are driven to it and don't give yourself other options. That way the setbacks that are inevitable when staring into the unknown void won't deter you.

Answer (score 1):

Academia certainly has some "research only" positions that do not have any teaching component; however, academic research positions of this kind will almost always entail applying for grants (unless you already have a large and long-lasting grant that makes this moot).  In fact, the more focused a position is on research, the more pressure there will be to apply for and secure grant funding.  Like any job, even in a " research only" academic position, you are going to have to do some other small administrative jobs, depending on your academic level.

The main difference between research in academia and industry is that in the former you have much broader discretion on choosing your own projects and deciding on the direction of your research.  Industry also has some pure research positions, but by their very nature, they are usually focused on researching particular problems that are of commercial value to the firms funding the research.  Another difference is that industry research positions often do not come with an expectation of applying for external funding.  In either case, even a job that is nominally "research only" will usually involve some small administrative burden.

In summary, it is possible to do "fundamental research" in both academia and industry, and there are some differences, but both will involve doing some tasks beyond your research.  I can understand the ideal of wanting to be left alone to pursue your research, without other tasks impeding this, but it is rare to be put in this ideal position.